# How to change the state of e.target.value with Redux/React?

Tags: reactjs, events, redux, react-redux

This is part of an extensive application so i will just post the relevant parts. I'm trying to implement an e.target.value onChange from my App.js up to the index.js file of the application. The app loads but breaks the moment a value is inserted in the input field and I'm referring to the mapDispatchToProps function:

```
App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import ToggleLayout from './components/ToggleLayout';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (

       <div>
          <Navbar
            searchTerm={this.props.searchItunes.searchTerm}
            onSearchChange={(e) =>this.props.onSearchChange(e.target.value)}
          /> 

          <ToggleLayout
            switchLayout={()=> this.props.switchLayout()}
            grid={this.props.toggle.grid}
          />
      </div>

    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    toggle: state.booleanReducer,
    searchItunes: state.searchItunesReducer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { 
    switchLayout: () => {
      dispatch({
        type:"GRID"
      });
    },
    onSearchChange: (e) => {
      dispatch({
        type:"SEARCHTERM",
        payload:e.target.value
      });
    }
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

and the index file is as below:

```
index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import  { Provider }  from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';


const booleanReducer = (state = { grid:true, additionalPages:false }, action) => {
  if (action.type === "GRID"){
    return state = {
      ...state,
      grid:!state.grid
    }
  }
  return state;
};

const searchItunesReducer = (state = { searchTerm:'', itunes:null }, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SEARCHTERM'){
    return state = {
      ...state,
      searchTerm:action.payload
      }
    }
  }


const store = createStore(combineReducers({booleanReducer,searchItunesReducer}));
console.log(store.getState());

store.subscribe(() =>{
  console.log("store updated!", store.getState());
});


registerServiceWorker();
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The switch layout function works as intended, so could you tell me what I'm doing wrong with the onSearchChange function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Navbar` component you're passing `onSearchChange` prop as an anonymous function that calls `this.props.onSearchChange` with `e.target.value` - so you're passing the exact value to the callback while the callback in `mapDispatchToProps` you're defining `onSearchChange` as a function that accepts the change event. That's why you're getting an error when you change the search input value.

You have 2 options here, either you pass just an event to `onSearchChange` in the `Navbar` component:

`<Navbar searchTerm={this.props.searchItunes.searchTerm}
        onSearchChange={this.props.onSearchChange} />`

or change the `onSearchChange` signature so that it accepts only the final value:

`onSearchChange: (value) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "SEARCHTERM",
    payload: value
  });
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Navbar
  searchTerm={this.props.searchItunes.searchTerm}
  onSearchChange={(e) =>this.props.onSearchChange(e.target.value)}
/>
```

In the method call you are sending the value of the event, your search term, so in `mapDispatchToProps` you don't need to send the whole event again, you just need to send the string you are setting in `onSearchChange`, because in your reducer you are setting the full action payload to the `searchTerm` reducer attribute.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { 
    switchLayout: () => {
      dispatch({
        type:"GRID"
      });
    },
    onSearchChange: (term) => {
      dispatch({
        type:"SEARCHTERM",
        payload: term,
      });
    }
  };
};
```